# React native:how to get Text value on a button click?

Tags: react-native

I have a `Text`,  and I want to get text value on click.

for example

```
click()
{
    // how to get text value here 
}

<Text style={{color: 'red,textAlign:'center'}} onPress={this.click.bind(this)}>
    Name
</Text>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use ref attribute to access Text's value.

```
<Text ref='myText'>This is my text</Text>
<Button onPress={()=>alert(this.refs.myText.props.children)} title='Press Me'/>
```

Comment: Let me know how do with dynamic Text

Comment: if you want to use dynamic @Himanshu Dwivedi answer is good for you. Use state to store the dynamic value. To change the state, just use this.setState({titleText:'This is new value'}) on any function you want inside the component.

Answer (score 3):

Can be done this way too...

```
<Text onPress={(event) => console.log(event._dispatchInstances.memoizedProps.children)} >{value}</Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do maintaining the text inside the state and get the text value when button is clicked.

```
export default class SampleApp extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      titleText: "Click to get text! - ",
      count:1
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Text style={{color:'black'}} onPress={()=>{this.onPressTitle()}}>
          {this.state.titleText}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  onPressTitle(){
    alert(this.state.titleText+this.state.count);
    this.setState({count:this.state.count+1});
  }
}
```

Works fine with dynamic text.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it has worked with `console.log(event._dispatchInstances.memoizedProps.children[0].props.children)`